# Wordpress custom plugin file upload - $_FILE is empty?

Tags: php, file-upload, wordpress

I'm coding a wordpress plugin that's supposed to do a few small things:

1) The user can upload a file (ideally a csv file, but that's irrelevant right now).

2) The plugin opens the file, reads the data from it, performs several operations with it, then deletes it.

Now, I'm having problems with step 1) specifically. While I already have the part where the plugin uses the data to perform its task and while I know how to open a file once it's in the server, I can't seem to be able to get it in the server. Specifically, because `$_FILES` seems to be empty. Here's my variable declaration space:

```
function register_random_plugin_settings() {
    register_setting( 'random-plugin-settings-group', 'random_plugin_data1' );
    register_setting( 'random-plugin-settings-group', 'random_plugin_uploadedfile' );
}
```

Here's my settings page function:

```
function page_injector_display_settings() {
    do_random_thing();
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Random Parameters</h2>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'random-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'random-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Data 1</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="random_plugin_data1" id="random_plugin_data1" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">CSV File</th>
        <td>
            <input type="file" id="random_plugin_uploadedfile" name="random_plugin_uploadedfile" />
        </td>
        </tr>


    </table>

    <?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>
<?php }
```

And here's a simplification of my handler, `do_random_thing()`:

```
function do_random_thing(){
    if((esc_attr( get_option('random_plugin_data1') ) != '')){

        $data1 = esc_attr( get_option('random_plugin_data1') );

        var_dump($_FILES);

        //Here we have everything the plugin does, unnecessary now.

        echo "<h2>Your will has been done.</h2>";

        update_option( 'random_plugin_data1', '');

    }
}
```

Problem is, as I stated before, that `var_dump($_FILES)` is empty. And with it empty, I can't do anything with the file I'm supposed to upload and read. I can't even know if it has been uploaded. I have tried by changing:

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
```

to

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="options.php">
```

To better mimic how a regular PHP file upload would work. But when I do that not only does `$_FILES` remain empty, but also all variables like `esc_attr( get_option('random_plugin_data1') )` end up empty.

I have noticed that `$_POST` is also empty always, but of course this isn't a problem because I can get the variables with `get_option`, so am I missing something here? I have spent hours scouring the net with no answer as to what I might be doing wrong. Can somebody point me in the right direction with this?